# How do i sort years in freemarker?

Tags: sorting, freemarker

I've seen couple of posts in which you've probably already answered my question, but I'm still not able to do it. Probably because I started working with freemarker two weeks ago...

```
<#assign translations = {
   "de":{
       "BBO":"Per {0}",
       "year01":"Baujahr",
       "refurbishment01":"Abgeschlossene Instandsetzungen:",
       "refurbishment02":"Instandsetzungen Jahre 1-10",
       "Detail00":"Konstruktion",
       "Detail01":"Dach",
       "Detail02":"Fassade",
       "Detail03":"Fenster",
       "Detail04":"Sanitär/Bäder",
       "Detail05":"Bodenbeläge",
       "Detail06":"Wand-/Deckenverkleidung",
       "Detail07":"Küche",
       "Detail08":"Wärmeverteilung",
       "Detail09":"Wärmeerzeugung",
       "Detail10":"Sanitärleitungen",
       "Detail11":"Elektrische Verteilung",
       "Detail12":"Lüftung",
       "Detail13":"Transportanlagen",
       "Detail14":"Parkierung",
       "Detail15":"",
       "totalinvest":"Total Investitionen:"
   },
   "en":{
       "BBO":"Per {0}",
        "year01":"Construction year",
       "refurbishment01":"Previous CAPEX:",
       "refurbishment02":"CAPEX years 1-10",
       "Detail00":"Construction",
       "Detail01":"Roof",
       "Detail02":"Facade",
       "Detail03":"Window",
       "Detail04":"Bathrooms",
       "Detail05":"Floor coverings",
       "Detail06":"Wall coverings",
       "Detail07":"Kitchen",
       "Detail08":"Heat distribution",
       "Detail09":"Heat production",
       "Detail10":"Sanitary line",
       "Detail11":"Electricity distribution",
       "Detail12":"Ventilation",
       "Detail13":"Transport system",
       "Detail14":"Parking",
       "Detail15":"Miscellaneous",
     "totalinvest":"Total CAPEX:"

   },
   "fr":{
       "BBO":"Per {0}",
       "Detail00":"Constuction",
       "Detail01":"Toit",
       "Detail15":"Diverses"
   }
}>

<#assign msg= translations[.lang]>
<#assign currency = valuation.valuationSettings.valuationCurrency>
<#assign BewJahr = valuation.valuationSettings.valuationDate.year>

<#assign buildings = valuation.valuationObject.buildings[0].buildingConstructions>
${msg["year01"]}:
<#list buildings as constructions>

${constructions.constructionYear?string["#####"]} 
   <#if constructions.comment??>
   <#assign comment= "("+constructions.comment+")"> 
   <#else> 
   <#assign comment = " ">
   </#if>
${comment}
<br> <br>
</#list>

<#if (valuation.valuationObject.buildings[0].buildingRenovations[0].lastTotalRenovationYear)??>
<#assign titlerenovations= msg["refurbishment01"]>
<#else>
<#assign titlerenovations= "">
</#if>

${titlerenovations}

<#assign renovations= valuation.valuationObject.buildings[0].buildingRenovations>
   <#if renovations??>     
       <#list renovations as renovation>
       <li>${renovation.lastTotalRenovationYear?string["0000"]} ${renovation.comment!}</li>
       </#list>
   </#if>

<#assign reco = valuation.valuationObject.reco>
<#list reco.buildings as building>
<#if building??>
<#assign intro01 = msg["refurbishment02"]+":">
<#else> <#assign intro01= "">
</#if>
<br>${intro01}

<#list building.componentGroups as group>



        <#list group.components as component>

           <#if component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "BATHROOMS">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail04"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "WALL_COVERINGS">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail06"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "FLOOR_COVERINGS">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail05"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "KITCHEN">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail07"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "TRANSPORT_SYSTEM">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail13"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "ROOF">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail01"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "WINDOW">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail03"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "FACADE">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail02"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "MISCELLANEOUS">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail15"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "ELECTRICITY_DISTRIBUTION">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail11"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "VENTILATION">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail12"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "SANITARY_LINE">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail10"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "HEAT_PRODUCTION">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail09"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "HEAT_DISTRIBUTION">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail08"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "PARKING">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail14"]>
            <#elseif component.componentType?? && component.componentType= "CONSTRUCTION">
            <#assign type = msg["Detail00"]>
          </#if>
            <#if component.details.firstRefurbishmentBudget?? && component.details.firstRefurbishmentBudget gte 0.1
                && (component.details.firstRefurbishmentStart.year)?? && component.details.firstRefurbishmentEnd.year??
                && component.details.firstRefurbishmentStart.year <= BewJahr+10>
                <#assign start= component.details.firstRefurbishmentStart.year?string["0000"]>
                <#assign end = component.details.firstRefurbishmentEnd.year?string["0000"]>
                    <#if start = end>
                        <#assign years = start+":">
                        <#elseif start != end>
                        <#assign years = start + "/" + end+":">
                    </#if>
            <#if type??>
            <#assign refurb = msg["refurbishment02"]>
           </#if>
           <#if component.details.firstRefurbishmentComment??>
                <#assign comment="("+component.details.firstRefurbishmentComment+")">
                <#else>
                <#assign comment="">
            </#if>
<li> ${years} ${type} ${currency} ${component.details.firstRefurbishmentBudget} ${comment}

       </#if>
       </#list>

</#list>
<#list reco.buildings as total>
<br><br> ${msg["totalinvest"]} ${currency} ${total.details.firstRefurbishmentBudget!}
</#list>
</#list>
<#assign BewJahr = valuation.valuationSettings.valuationDate.year>
```

The output is:
CAPEX years 1-10:

- 2025/2026: Facade EUR 20'000
- 2029: Windows EUR 15'000
- 2018/2019: Floor coverings EUR 25'000
- 2017: Miscellaneous EUR 2'000

I need these years in an order, starting with the first (2017, 2018/2019, 2025/2026, 2029).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary list and add all lines to it. Print them sorted just after the loop:

```
<#assign templist = []/>
<#list building.componentGroups as group>
    ....
    <#assign templist = templist + ["${years} ${type} ${currency} ${component.details.firstRefurbishmentBudget} ${comment}"]/>
</#list>

<#list templist?sort as item>
    <li> ${item} </li>
</#list>
```